# Does Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise edition provide design for Xamrin Page?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I have Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise Edition with latest update. I want to run Xamrin application.

I have create new XAML page. But I didn't get design page. So, I need to write code of design and run application to check whether design is proper or not. This takes too much time.

Can anybody please suggest me why there is no design view in XAML page?

Does Visual Studio 2017 provide design view for Xamrin Xaml page? I think it should provide.

One more thing I found from google that there is a tool to check design by compiling project: Xamrine.Form.Previewer (View --> Other Windows --> Xamrin.Forms.Previewer)

I have tried with this but it also doesn't work.

Please guide
[image]

Comment: no, Xamarin Forms does not have a Designer for XAML pages

Answer (score 4):

Answer is **yes**, if you by design mean preview that you get from xaml code, and it is called Xamarin.Forms Previewer, it should work and it is included in Visual Studio Enterprise edition. However that **does not** mean that you have **WYSIWYG** editor.

Another thing is that you are getting a exception. You are not providing us full code of your XAML page so there is small chance for us to help you with this exception.

Also I strongly recommend you to take a look at **Xamarin Live Player**, using it you can test app code changes in real time on your iOS or Android device, you can find more about it [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/live/), it is a great tool made by Xamarin and it is way more better than Xamarin.Forms Previewer.